# Add to cart not working in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, error, addtocart, login, logout

I have same issue in Magento 1.9

i'm using magento 1.9.3.2

1. Login to a customer accounts
2. Try to add something to the shopping cart and place an order
3. After order is saved go back to store and try to add something else to the shopping cart.
4. It returns an error message: Cannot add the item to shopping cart.
5. If i logout and login back i can add the product to shopping cart and place order as normal

Comment: Are there any modifications in the checkout process or customer module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not save the quote item object in the observer, so just remove this line $quote_item->save(); It will save the object automatically, as it is being passed by reference.

[sales_quote_add_item - error on save quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024394/sales-quote-add-item-error-on-save-quote#answer-13026069)